# Core Data ManagedObject - Can't set attribute value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm having issues writing values to an attribute in a Core Data managed object. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here.. PSNDataSync is a singleton that I'm using to pass my managed object context around as well as hold other shared variables. I'm attempting to set the "path" attribute in my Image object.

Putting in a breakpoint shows that imageURL has a valid NSURL value and in my CoreData entity, path is set as type Transformable.

```
NSError *imgError = nil;
NSEntityDescription *imgED = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:[[PSNDataSync instance]context]];
Image *img = [[Image alloc] initWithEntity:imgED insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[[PSNDataSync instance]context]];

[img setValue:imageURL forKey:@"path"];
[img setInventory:(Inventory *)[[PSNDataSync instance]currentInventory]];

[[[PSNDataSync instance]context] insertObject:img];
[[[PSNDataSync instance]context] save:&imgError];
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? - Calling `insertObject` is not (as far as I know) necessary because the object has already been inserted using the `insertIntoManagedObjectContext` parameter.

Comment: Ok.. that might be my issue then, I'm probably inserting it before I set the value of the attribute. I need to init the Image object without inserting it.

Comment: No, inserting with insertIntoManagedObjectContext and then setting attributes is fine. What happens if you remove the `insertObject` call?

Comment: I GOT IT! The problem was with how I was representing my path attribute. I had it set as transformable and was trying to store an NSURL in there. I changed it to a String data type and set it with my imageURL.absoluteString and it's working.. It seems I need a better understanding of Transformable data type. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Oh.. and I did remove the extra insert.. thanks for the heads up!